# StringWriter vs StreamWriter wrapping MemoryStream - difference

Tags: c#, .net

I have following piece of code:

```
        byte[] snapthotBytes, snapthotBytes2;
        string stringOutput, stringOutput2;
        IInvestigationDump investigationDump = new HtmlSnapshotDump();
        using (TextWriter writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            investigationDump.Dump(investigation, writer);
            snapthotBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(writer.ToString());
            stringOutput = writer.ToString();
        } // end of first implementation

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            investigationDump.Dump(investigation, writer);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            stringOutput2 = reader.ReadToEnd();
            snapthotBytes2 = stream.ToArray();
        } // end of second implementation

        // stringOutput != stringOutput2 - content wise
        // snapthotBytes != snapthotBytes2 - content wise
```

Some introduction:

- Dump method just traverses **investigation** object and renders an HTML report (by writing to a writer object).
- Appart from the fact that StringWriter uses UTF-16 encoding and XML declaration will differ, both stringOutput & stringOutput2 should have the same content. **Dump** methods signature is:

`void Dump(IInvestigation investigation, TextWriter writer);`

- **Dump** method just writes to a writer, without any conditions etc.

At first I used MemoryStream code snippet, it was easier as I received byte[] straightaway. But soon I realized a bug. Amazingly it turned out that **stringOutput2** (produced by MemoryStream solution) is trimmed, it is shorter! It just ends with trimmed HTML content:

```
        <tr>
          <td>Certificate or License No</td>
          <td class="value">Friuan</td>
          <td>Place of Issue</td>
          <td class="value">Foruan</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Award Date</td>
          <td
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
writer.Flush()
```

before trying to read the stream?

Comment: You've got to be kidding me! :) It worked. But why? Could you elaborate? It didn't occur to me that I should flush when writing to MemoryStream.

Comment: I mean why I have to flush under this particular circumstances :)

Comment: It's because the StreamWriter buffers input and only flushes when the buffer is full, so that it can write more efficiently to the underlying Stream. No distinction is made between MemoryStream and other types of Stream.